# How to get the result of CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE and CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF in snowflake without using them?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to make hierarchical queries, and I need to get the results of CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE and CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF, but these features are supported in Oracle not in Snowflake.

What are the alternative ways to implement the functionalities of CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE and CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF in snowflake without using them as these keywords are not supported there?

Comment: I guess a code block/snippet can do the thing, but i cannot build the block.

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if you have taken a look at the following Snowflake features?

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/queries-hierarchical.html#using-connect-by-or-recursive-ctes-to-query-hierarchical-data

Answer (score 0):

Yes I took a look there. I also took a look at https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/connect-by.html where it clearly says that these features are not supported in Snowflake.
I was trying below code block to find an alternative but facing varieties of error in snowflake.

```
person_vertex as (
    select 
        emp_number, 
        user_id 
    from person
),

person_edges as ( 
    select 
        supervisor_emp_number, 
        emp_number 
    from person 
    where supervisor_emp_number is not null
),

select
    pv.emp_number emp_id_pk,
    level,
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT pv.emp_number AS root,
    concat(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(pv.emp_number,':'),':') as path,
    -- CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE AS iscyclic, ------------------- no idea how to implement this
    -- CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF as isleaf ------------------- i tried below block, but it is not working
    case
        when (pe.supervisor_emp_number in (select emp_number from pv)) then 0
        else 1
    end AS isleaf
from person_vertex pv
    left join person_edges pe on pv.emp_number = pe.emp_number
connect by prior A.emp_number = A.supervisor_emp_number
start with A.supervisor_emp_number is null
```

Any help with this block is really appreciated.

Thanks.

```
enter code here
```